# How do i correctly initialize Object streams with a cipher

Tags: java, stream, encryption

Server

```
 decCipher.init(Cipher.DECCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
     ois = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(),decCipher));
     encCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
     out = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),encCipher));
```

Client ( different application):

e

```
ncCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
obj_out = newObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),encCipher));
 decCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
 obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(),decCipher)
```

Ois in the server application threws an exception while creating the stream. How to fix it? When this is not wrapped iin the cipher Streams everything works.

The exception isnt thrown just when the `new ObjectInputStream` is  creating, but it freezes for 10 seconds (time out), and  when the time out limit is reached it threws an exception.

Exception:

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2298)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2767)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
```

Comment: Please provide more complete code fragments. Do you have separate desCipher objects, or are you maybe reusing object that you should not? Please provide a longer backtrace. Are your server and client properly split into two threads? Please be more patient, too.

Comment: I have updated the code but i dont know how to format it properly. sorry for that

Comment: Don't *reuse* the `desCipher` objects! I guess it cannot be initialized to encrypt and decrypt at the same time!

Comment: Time for you to confide in us what exception is thrown.

Comment: updated. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different `Cipher` objects, one for encrypting, one for decrypting. Consider the mode your `Cipher` object attached to the `CipherInputStream` is in after you put it into `ENCRYPT_MODE`.

Comment: With two different Cipher objects nothing has changed. I have also tried it with all combinations with ENCRPT/DECRYPT MODE but still the same.

Comment: @user1306777 The CipherInputStream needs a Cipher in DECRYPT mode. The CipherOutputStream needs a Cipher in ENCRYPT mode. You only need to initialize them once each, when creating the streams.

Comment: EJP still doesnt work, or i dont get you. I have updated the code that produces an exception.